# How to get black keyboard layout for Lollipop keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, color

I just updated my Nexus4 from Kitkat to Lollipop. The most obvious change for me is the background color of the theme and especially the keyboard. It used to have a black background, now its color is the brightest of whites hurting my poor eyes. Can I change the background color back into blackness, and if so, how?

Note: I like to avoid keyboard apps from third parties. I know they exist in different flavors, but I like to keep it native.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current layout is called "**Material Light**". To change it, though there isn't a pure black version, go to

> Settings > Language and Input > Google Keyboard > Appearance and Layouts

The dark material setting is called "**Material Dark**" and looks like this:

[image]

I'm assuming you want material design as you are keeping it stock, but there are the old KitKat 'Holo' themes in there also.

Answer (score 5):

Your current layout is called "Material Light". To change it, go to

```
Settings > Language and Input > Google Keyboard > Appearance and Layouts
```

Holo White matches the kitkat default appearence - dark gray background, light gray buttons with white letters